# Can anyone help interpret this script found on a metal ink box?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Metal box, 6cm by 6cm and 3 cm high. I believe it is an ink box. It has a metal frame inside that holds a piece of slate. The slate is in the top of box and the lower part of the box is lined with copper.

[image]

Comment: You haven't attached any photos.

Comment: `唯正月初吉丁亥，楚王媵邛仲嬭作嬭`, poor imitation from the opening text of 楚王鐘 《殷周金文集成》72

Comment: Thank you. I guess it will make another novelty on my dresser. 

Answer (score 3):

The characters are very deformed, but the best match to the writing looks like

> ##### 富䝿（貴）昌矦（侯）王

Flourishing wealth and prosperity, fitting for the noblemen and king.

> 隹（唯）正月初吉丁亥，䠂（楚）王賸（媵）邛（中＞仲）嬭（乍＞作）嬭

'Tis the day of [*dīnghài*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%81%E4%BA%A5) of the first week of the first month, and the King of [Chǔ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) gifts Second Lady 「嬭」 from the [State of 「邛」](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%B1%9F%E5%9C%8B) ... as dowry ...

Comment: I appreciate your comment. It seems as though the box could be  worth keeping.

Answer (score 3):

compare to the original text, it’s an extremely poor quality fake product

the original  is named “楚王鐘” in 殷周金文集成 (00072), or named as “楚邛仲南和鐘” in 歷代鍾鼎彝器款識法帖 卷六:

[image]

https://archive.org/details/06052850.cn/page/n139/mode/2up

Comment: Thank you for your quick response